# Parse data from one CSV file to another

Tags: csv, macros, openoffice.org, openoffice-basic

I'm trying to run this Macro but since my CSV file is really long and I don't want to count the column numbers, is there a way to reference the column by the letters such as "DZ"?  The code works fine but I just need to reference these deep columns and don't want to count which column number it is and can't seem to find a way to display the column number.  I have been setting 'c' & 't' as the column number such as 1, 2, etc.

```
Sub ParseColumn

Dim sheet1 as Object
Dim sheet2 as Object
Dim r as long
Dim c as long

sheet1 = ThisComponent.Sheets.getbyname("Sheet1")
sheet2 = ThisComponent.Sheets.getbyname("Sheet2")

c = F
t = DZ

for r = 1 to 18739

    copyFrom = sheet1.getCellByPosition(c,r)

    copyTo = sheet2.getCellByPosition(t,r)

    copyTo.String = copyFrom.String 

next r

End Sub
```

**Update**
Found a solution:

```
Sub ParseColumn

Dim sheet1 as Object
Dim sheet2 as Object
Dim r as long

sheet1 = ThisComponent.Sheets.getbyname("Sheet1")
sheet2 = ThisComponent.Sheets.getbyname("Sheet2")

for r = 2 to 18739

    copyFrom = sheet1.getCellRangeByName("AR" & r)

    copyTo = sheet2.getCellRangeByName("S" & r)

    copyTo.String = copyFrom.String 

next r

End Sub
```

Comment: found a solution: 

    Sub ParseColumn

 Dim sheet1 as Object
 Dim sheet2 as Object
 Dim r as long
 
 sheet1 = ThisComponent.Sheets.getbyname("Sheet1")
 sheet2 = ThisComponent.Sheets.getbyname("Sheet2")
 
 for r = 2 to 18739
 
  copyFrom = sheet1.getCellRangeByName("Y" & r)
  
  copyTo = sheet2.getCellRangeByName("Q" & r)
  
  copyTo.String = copyFrom.String 
  
 next r

    End Sub

Comment: It is also possible to get the range of used cells in a sheet, just something to think about.